# How do I join multiple records into a single record in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Here is my input table:

```
ID    Position  Email  
1     1         email1  
1     2         email2  
1     3         email3  
2     1         emaila  
3     1         emailz  
3     2         emaily
```

This is the output table I'd like to fill:

```
ID  primary_email Secondary_email    
1   email1        email2  
2   emaila  
3   emailz        emaily
```

Comment: asked a bazillion times previously....please try searching

Comment: I spent quite awhile searching but didn't find anything quite like this

Comment: You write "input file", but mention SQL. This does not make sense, as SQL operates on database tables, not on files. Do you mean that what you list is a database table?

Comment: Where is the input coming from?

Comment: Yes... if you use "row" instead of "line", and "table" instead of "file", you should get better search results ;) Anyway, concatenation depends a bit on the RDBMS you are using. Different engines have different functions for that. And you are not telling us what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have used the word Table instead of file.

Comment: The table is in Microsoft SQL.

Comment: Fixed the question to use "record" and "table" instead of talking about files.

Comment: More specifically, this is running on MS SQL server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 1 THEN Email ELSE '' END) AS primary_email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 2 THEN Email ELSE '' END) AS Secondary_email
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```